# Image does not show in my slide

Tags: html, css

i want a small slide in the left side bar.
but i cant find it to work and i dont know what is wrong with it.
did google searches count find anything that could help.
if someone know anything i like to hear from u.

ps: yes part of css code is not my its a reset sheet i used, my code is marked below /*-----mycode-----*/.

```css
/*!doctype CSS*/
/* 
html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet
v1.6.1
Last Updated: 2010-09-17
Author: Richard Clark - http://richclarkdesign.com 
Twitter: @rich_clark
*/

html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/*----------MY CODE----------*/

.wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*-----NOT IN USE-----*/
.wrapperart {
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
 border-width: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
 border-style: solid;
}
/*-----NOT IN USE-----*/

/*-----Header-----*/

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
 background: #222;
}

header img {
 width: 240px;
 height: 120px;
 float: left;
}

header nav {
 float: right;
}

header nav ul {
 margin-top: 40px;
}

header nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 20px;
 list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li a {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 background-color: black;
}

nav ul li div{
 display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover div{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

/*-----body-----*/
.mainbody {
 width: 50%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-weigt: 400;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}

div.mainbody div {
 padding: 30px 0px;
}

.mainbody h1 {
 font-weight: 400;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

.luisterdiv {
 width: 120px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: #333;
 z-index: 0;
}

.sidebarleft {
 width: 25%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div.sidebarleft div {
 height: 800px;
 border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.sidebarright {
 width: 25%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 float: right;
}

div.sidebarright div {
 width: 470px;
 height: 800px;
 border-left: 2px solid black;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
 display: block;
 width: 940px;
 height: 800px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.slide {
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 470px;
 height: 800px;
}

li img {
 height: 800px;
 width: 470px;
 float: left;
}

/*-----footer-----*/
footer {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #222;
 padding: 60px 0px;
 clear: both;
}

footer nav {
 float: left;
}

footer nav ul {
 color: white;
}

footer nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 20px;
 list-style: none;
}

footer nav ul li a {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>VeluweAM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

 <header>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <img src="verzamelbak/image/Logo.png">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="programma.html">Programma</a></li>
     <li><a href="luisteren.html">Luisteren</a>
      <div class="luisterdiv">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="http://93.190.142.179:8126/stream.html">In Browser</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://tunein.com/radio/VeluweAM-s299064">Tunein</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://panel.beheerstream.com:2199/tunein/veluweam.pls">Winamp</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://panel.beheerstream.com:2199/tunein/veluweam.asx">Windows Media Player</a></li>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li><a href="over ons.html">Over ons</a></li>
     <li><a href="onze dj.html">Onze DJ's</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 
 <div class="sidebarleft">
  <div>
   <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide"><img src"verzamelbal/image/cpu.png"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src"verzamelbal/image/cpu2.png"></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="mainbody">
  <div class="mainbodydiv">
   <article>
    <h1>Welcome op VeluweAM, Nieuws uit de regio.</h1>
    <p>het radio stations die voor alles wat heeft.</p>
    <p>heeft u nog niet gezien wat wij in huis hebben?<br>
    bekijken ons programma, ik kan u garanderen dat u iets vind!</P>
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="sidebarright">
  <div>
   
  </div>
  
 </div>

 <footer>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     ©2017 VeluweAM
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="programma.html">Programma</a></li>
     <li><a href="Luisteren.html">Luisteren</a>
     <li><a href="over ons.html">Over ons</a></li>
     <li><a href="onze dj.html">Onze DJ's</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </footer>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You missed a `=` in your image tags – `<img src"verzamelbal/image/cpu.png">` should be `<img src="verzamelbal/image/cpu.png">`

Comment: Are you sure the image is located in /verzamelbaL, and not /verzamelbaK?

Comment: yea the verzameba(k) i did fix allready after i posted this, i dont see that mistake.   
i love coding but freaking typos,

Answer (score 0):

if your image location is correct, i think your html/php file is inside a folder that is why you need to locate it using **../** and then your image location.

Comment: i dont have my index in a folder, so i sould not have to back out of that folder, if i do so i will end up on my desktop.

only my image is on a folder, and so i my css in a folder.
but my  index pages, etc are in the main folder.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the "="

if i change to online image it's ok

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
/*!doctype CSS*/
/* 
html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet
v1.6.1
Last Updated: 2010-09-17
Author: Richard Clark - http://richclarkdesign.com 
Twitter: @rich_clark
*/

html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/*----------MY CODE----------*/

.wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*-----NOT IN USE-----*/
.wrapperart {
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
 border-width: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
 border-style: solid;
}
/*-----NOT IN USE-----*/

/*-----Header-----*/

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
 background: #222;
}

header img {
 width: 240px;
 height: 120px;
 float: left;
}

header nav {
 float: right;
}

header nav ul {
 margin-top: 40px;
}

header nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 20px;
 list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li a {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 background-color: black;
}

nav ul li div{
 display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover div{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

/*-----body-----*/
.mainbody {
 width: 50%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-weigt: 400;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}

div.mainbody div {
 padding: 30px 0px;
}

.mainbody h1 {
 font-weight: 400;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

.luisterdiv {
 width: 120px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: #333;
 z-index: 0;
}

.sidebarleft {
 width: 25%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div.sidebarleft div {
 height: 800px;
 border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.sidebarright {
 width: 25%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 float: right;
}

div.sidebarright div {
 width: 470px;
 height: 800px;
 border-left: 2px solid black;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
 display: block;
 width: 940px;
 height: 800px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.slide {
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 470px;
 height: 800px;
}

li img {
 height: 800px;
 width: 470px;
 float: left;
}

/*-----footer-----*/
footer {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #222;
 padding: 60px 0px;
 clear: both;
}

footer nav {
 float: left;
}

footer nav ul {
 color: white;
}

footer nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 20px;
 list-style: none;
}

footer nav ul li a {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: white;
}</style>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>VeluweAM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

 <header>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="programma.html">Programma</a></li>
     <li><a href="luisteren.html">Luisteren</a>
      <div class="luisterdiv">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="http://93.190.142.179:8126/stream.html">In Browser</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://tunein.com/radio/VeluweAM-s299064">Tunein</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://panel.beheerstream.com:2199/tunein/veluweam.pls">Winamp</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://panel.beheerstream.com:2199/tunein/veluweam.asx">Windows Media Player</a></li>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li><a href="over ons.html">Over ons</a></li>
     <li><a href="onze dj.html">Onze DJ's</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 
 <div class="sidebarleft">
  <div>
   <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png"></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="mainbody">
  <div class="mainbodydiv">
   <article>
    <h1>Welcome op VeluweAM, Nieuws uit de regio.</h1>
    <p>het radio stations die voor alles wat heeft.</p>
    <p>heeft u nog niet gezien wat wij in huis hebben?<br>
    bekijken ons programma, ik kan u garanderen dat u iets vind!</P>
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="sidebarright">
  <div>
   
  </div>
  
 </div>

 <footer>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     ©2017 VeluweAM
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="programma.html">Programma</a></li>
     <li><a href="Luisteren.html">Luisteren</a>
     <li><a href="over ons.html">Over ons</a></li>
     <li><a href="onze dj.html">Onze DJ's</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </footer>
 
</body>

</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide"><img src"verzamelbal/image/cpu.png"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img src"verzamelbal/image/cpu2.png"></li>
        </ul>
```

You have error here (missing '=') : it should be img src=" " 
But I think u are still missing mechanism for slide, now it will only display first image and cover the second one.

U need some javascript.. simplest example: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self

Comment: ty, stupid misstake, how could i have missed that.
i will fix it right now,

Comment: It won't solve the sliding problem I guess :) I edited the post and placed a link in it, You should check it out.

Comment: i have not worked with javascript yet, so i will start working on learning that.
i am gonna try to make is slide automaticly after so many sec,
i fell so stupid tho , that u missed just a simple =  in the code.
img still doenst show, but i that an other error, i will be able to fix that.


still thanks a lot for the help:D

Comment: For me it works http://prntscr.com/h4t8fw, do You have Your images in those folders: verzamelbal/image/ ? and you still have some unused closing tags (div and li)  + wrong </P> tag (it should be </p>

Comment: yea i got it working, i was useing the wrong test images i had read,
so i changed some test images, it is working correctly now,
only have to code in the slide effect etc.

Comment: yea i am going to all my code right now to check every thing thanks for letting me know:D